# Remove Duplicate from Array of Object

Tags: object, duplicates, arrayobject

Iam having an array of Object

```
       [
                {
                REQUEST_TYPE: 3,
                 E_APN: [ 'internet' ],
                 value:0
                 },
                 {  
                  REQUEST_TYPE: 3,
                  E_APN: [ 'internet' ],
                 value:0,
                 },
                  {
                  REQUEST_TYPE: 2,
                   E_APN: [ 'login' ]
                    value:0,
           
          }
    ]
```

if REQUEST_TYPE of each object is same, then it should merge E_APN as shown below:

```
 [
                {
                REQUEST_TYPE: 3,
                 E_APN: [ 'internet','internet' ],
                 value:0,
                 },
                
                  {
                  REQUEST_TYPE: 2,
                   E_APN: [ 'login' ],
                   value:0
          }
    ]
```

In tried using filter

```
const resultArr = dataArr.filter((data,index)=>{
  return dataArr.indexOf(data) === index;
})
```

but not able to push E_APN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dup = [
   {
      REQUEST_TYPE: 3,
      E_APN: ['internet'],
      value: 0
   },
   {
      REQUEST_TYPE: 3,
      E_APN: ['internet'],
      value: 0,
   },
   {
      REQUEST_TYPE: 2,
      E_APN: ['login'],
      value: 0,

   }
]

var unique = []
var ref = {}
var t = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < dup.length; i++) {
   if (unique[ref[dup[i].REQUEST_TYPE]]) {
      unique[ref[dup[i].REQUEST_TYPE]].E_APN = (unique[ref[dup[i].REQUEST_TYPE]].E_APN).concat(dup[i].E_APN)
   } else {
      ref[dup[i].REQUEST_TYPE] = t++;
      unique.push(dup[i])
   }
}
console.log(unique)
```